# Linear Programming conceptual question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Linear programming involves solving a linear problem subject to the constraint $x \geq  0$, and minimizing a Cost function for the specific case.

The book (Gilbert Strang, Linear Algebra, section on Linear Programming), states that in Linear Programming, if we have $m$ equations, $n$ unknowns ($n > m$ as an under determined system of equations). Then the number of corners is $n!/m!(n-m)!$.

Taking a plane $x1 + x2 + x3 = 4$, a corner-example would be $(0,4,0)$. (useful for reading the extract.)

- When it is stated that for $m$ equations there is a large number of corners with $m$ non-zeroes, where does this come from?
- Maybe a single example for 2 3D planes would help me understand better.

---

> [image]

---

PS: in this case, according to the definition, corner would always be $(x,0,0)$, $(0,y,0)$, $(0,0,z)$ but here is an intuition from the book

- It is a vector $x \geq 0$ such that at most $m$ components are non-zero, and is a solution to $Ax=b$.

Applied to the example, with a single equation, at most 1 component is non-zero.

Comment: You might find it easier to think of corners as points corresponding to a complete set of equations. The fact that $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ gives us one equation in your single-plane example. The "corners" of the region are each an intersection of this boundary-plane with two boundary-planes; for instance, the $x_1$-axis corner is the intersection of this plane with the boundaries $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$ (corresponding to the constraints $x_2,x_3 \geq 0$).

Comment: In order to specify a (unique) corner point in a 2-dimensional plane, we need two further pieces of information, hence the need for the two equations $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense for an example to take place on "2 3D planes"; the set of points satisfying $A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ would be on the *intersection* of two planes, which is to say it would be on a line in 3D space. For a line, it's clear that specifying $3-2 = 1$ plane of the form $x_i = 0$ is sufficient for specifying a "corner" of this line. Note, however, that the line within the positive octant should only have two "corners", so one of those intersections must lie beyond the region of interest.

Comment: Which version of the book?

Answer (score 1):

### **Simple 3D example**

We have 2 linearly independent equations in 3 unknowns:

$x+y+z=1$

$x + y = 0.5$

The plot of these two planes (first one is blue, second is purple), their intersection (red), and two "corner points" (green dots) for $x,y,z \geq 0$ looks like this:

[image]

According to Strang, we should have 3 corner points since there are ${3 \choose 2} = 3$ ways to make this underdetermined system "determinate".

**Case 1: $x=0$**

We get the reduced system

$y+z=1$

$y = 0.5$

Corner point is $(0,0.5,0.5)$

**Case 2: $y=0$**

We get the reduced system

$x+z=1$

$x = 0.5$

Corner points is $(.5,0,0.5)$

So far so good -- now for the last corner point.

**Case 3: $z=0$**

We get the reduced system

$x+y=1$

$x+y = 0.5$

Corner point *does not exist* as the above system is inconsistent.

In fact, even the two "corner points" are not actually corners of anything. they are points along a line. These points just happen to be where we've set one of the variables equal to zero.

---

I think you are confused by the book's explanation because it's using words loosely. As the above example shows, these solutions are not really "corners" of anything (unless we get into half-planes -- which I get into below but it's more technical).

In addition, not every such system is consistent, so some of the $m \choose n$ choices will not even have a solution.

The true number of corner points to check in a linear programming problem is not $m \choose n$. The remainder of this answer dives into this point.

All $m \choose n$ is telling us is the number of ways to create "determinate" systems out of an indeterminate system.

---

In linear programming we deal with feasible regions that are (geometrically) [convex polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope), which result from the intersection of half-planes (e.g., linear inequalities such as $x + y \leq 2$).

A convex polytope in $n$ dimensions (i.e., "unknowns" per Strang) and defined by $k$ half-planes (i.e., constraints or "equations" per Strang) can have at most:

$${k-\lceil n/2 \rceil \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + {k-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1 \choose \lceil n/2 \rceil - 1}$$

vertices (i.e., corner points) [See [here]](https://mathoverflow.net/a/127426) and [page 12 of this text](http://www.csun.edu/%7Ectoth/Handbook/chap15.pdf) - this comes from the fact the class of convex polytopes called "cyclic polytopes" maximize the number of facets of the polytope. Then, there is a "dual" of this polytope that has a vertex corresponding to each facet of the original (non-dual or "primal").

Note that this can be much less than the suggested $k \choose n$ in Strang's book, since:

$${k \choose n} = {k-1 \choose n} + {k-1 \choose n-1}$$

---

A simple counter-example in two dimensions is a set of box constraints in the $x-y$ plane:

$$0 \leq x \leq 1,\;\; 0\leq y\leq1$$

Putting this into standard form (i.e., $\leq$ for all) we get:

$$x \leq 1,\; y\leq 1\; -x \leq 0,\; -y \leq 0$$

We get the matrix form of this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\\-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

There are four corners in this example: $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$

How do we get these points from our matrix formulation?

In general, a corner point in $n-$space will be at the intersection of $n$ inequality constraints (since we have $n$ unknowns and need a unique solution, so we need $n$ equations); note that **the converse is not true in general**: not every $n$ equations will represent a valid corner point...more on that below.

This particular matrix is $4\times 1$ (four equations) but we have only two unknowns (i.e., we are in $2-$space). We need to reduce the dimensionality of the matrix to $2 \times 2$ so it is consistent.

To do this, we choose two constraints to be "tight" (i.e., no slack in the constraint, so it's an equality) and solve the reduced system.

**Following Strang's logic**, we choose any two constraints $i,j$ among the four available constraints, to form the reduced system (using partitioned matrix notation for the reduced $A$ matrix):

$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{i,\cdot} \\ A_{j,\cdot}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}_{\text{corner}} = \begin{bmatrix}b_i \\b_j \end{bmatrix} \implies  \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix}_{\text{corner}} = \begin{bmatrix}b_i \\b_j \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A_{i,\cdot} \\ A_{j,\cdot}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

How many ways can we select $m$ out of $n$ things? That is given by the combination formula you will learn in probability classes:

$${n \choose m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

So here we get:

$${4 \choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!(2)!} = \frac{24}{4} = 6$$

Huh?! We should only have $4$ vertices since our feasible region is a $1 \times 1$ square.

What happened?

**Not every reduced system is consistent!** Specifically, there is no corner point associated with:

1. Setting $-x \leq 0,\; x\leq 1$ to be tight since $x$ cannot be equal to two things at the same time.
2. By the same reasoning, setting $-y \leq 0,\; y\leq 1$ is not a corner point.

Omitting these two we get back to the $4$ corner points we expect and consistent with the correct upper bound:

$${4-\lceil 2/2 \rceil \choose \lfloor 2/2 \rfloor} + {4-\lfloor 2/2 \rfloor - 1 \choose \lceil 2/2 \rceil - 1} = {3 \choose 1} + {2 \choose 0} = 3 + 1 = 4$$

Comment: I wish I could follow it, I'm too simple for this. So I will relay in other's upvotes to accept.. Do you know any somewhat introductory book I could check ? I did notice though, that these problems were under-determined, but I thought this was linear programming, and over-determined was quadratic programming.

Comment: You can skip to the box constraint example -- its a square with four corner points but the combinations formula would tell you there are 6. He's assuming every subset of equations is consistent.

Comment: Linear vs quadratic programming has nothing to do with under or over determined -- its the functional form of the objective function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: I see, I assume **cost** is the same, and thank you, I get the difference now.

Comment: @MahNeh --- I think the challenge is that his example is vaguely related to linear programming, but very very tangentially. Really what he is saying is there are $n \choose m$ ways to create a system with a unique solution from an underdetermined system. Those solutions are at the intersection of a "reduced system" where $n-m$ variables are set to $0$.

Comment: @MahNeh -- added a simple example at the top -- hope that helps :)